# Unable to select nodes of a Dijit Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have created a simple dijit tree as follows :

```
var myDataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore(
         {data: { identifier: 'id', label : 'label', items: myData }});

var myModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({ store: myDataStore });


new dijit.Tree({ model: myModel,
         showRoot: false,
       }, "myTree" );
```

myData is a JSON with format like { id : '1' label : 'nodeName'}

Tree is succesfully created. however i am unable to select a node.As soon as i move the mouse away from a node it gets deselected.
I need to select a node and perform a operation based on the selected node

What am i missing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
onClick: function(item){
    //perform operation based on selected node
}
```

to your `dijit.Tree`.

Comment: thanks.but i have one more question > is there any way to change the background color of the selected node.

Comment: check which class is added to the node when it is selected and override its background color in your own css.

Comment: ya that will work. but what if i want to select more than one node by using cntrl key. Im thinking maybe theres a more easier way to do this